# Why is list data not updating?

Tags: c#, android, list, listview

I have a custom adapter for a list view which is inside a method that gets called on the OnCreate and gets initialized after user presses a AlertDialog button.

```
  private List<Sensor> checkedList;
  private ConfigureAdapter configureAdapter;
  private ListView listView;

  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        { 
               listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.sensorList);
               listView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick;
               SetUp();
        }
```

```
  private void SetUp()
        {
            ...
            aircraftView.SetPositiveButton("Select", delegate
                {
                    checkedList = sensorDisplayList.Where(o => o.Checked == true).ToList();
                      configureAdapter = new ConfigureAdapter(this, checkedList);

                      {
                        listView.Adapter = configureAdapter;
                        configureAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

                      };

                });
         
        }
```

So,  on the listview item click, I create a PopUp Menu and once an item is clicked on the pop up menu, I update the listview data to reflect this.

```
  private  void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
         if (checkedList != null)
            {
                Sensor sensor = checkedList[e.Position];
                
                PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(this, listView.GetChildAt(e.Position));
                if (mTirePositionList == null)
                {
                    DisplayError("Error.");
                }
                else
                {
                     
                    ...
                    menu.MenuItemClick += (s1, arg1) =>
                    {
                        sensor.WheelPosition = arg1.Item.ToString();
                        checkedList[e.Position].WheelPosition = arg1.Item.ToString();
                        configureAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();


                    };
                    menu.Show();
                }
            }
        }
```

The ListView UI is then updated, but when I reference **checkedList** in another method after updating it in the the event, the list does not reflect that change. Why? What am I not understanding?

Comment: Add break point in the OnCreate and see if you are getting to the event.

Comment: @jdweng yes, all events are triggered appropriately. UI for list adapter updates. The only thing that doesn't seem to "save" update is the list itself.

Comment: Then you are not using the same instance of the listview if it is updating in one part of the code and note the other or the NotifyDataSetChanged isn't working.

Comment: @jdweng When I moved the initialization of the adapter from inside the AlertDialog button click and straight into the OnCreate, the list data updates correctly and everything is fixed. Why? Is it creating a new instance if I leave it inside the dialog click event in SetUp()? Is there a way I could keep the initialization of the adapter inside the click event?

Comment: @jdweng Scratch that, it's actually the initialization of my checkedList that's the issue. Initializing the adapter inside the click event works as long as my checkedList was initialized on the OnCreate(). My knowledge on instances is not strong, so I'm still confused on why this is the case.

Comment: Class object in c# are By Reference (not By Value).  Why do you need to have a new addptor instead of only one adapter? :  configureAdapter = new ConfigureAdapter(this, checkedList);

Comment: The adapter has links to the DataSet.  So when items change the DataSet get updated with the NotifyDataSetChanged().  you should only create a new adapter when the DataSet is created.  If you use new with the adapter then the links are broken back to the DataSet.

Comment: Right now I can only create the adapter after my list is populated which happens on button click event. I don't know how I can create adapter without using new?

Comment: I said new adapter should be called once.  You dataset is sensorDisplayList which is all the items.  The adapter should be on the  sensorDisplayList.  The view is checkedList.